# fast remove ending string from other string scala

Tags: string, scala, substring, strip, suffix

I have such string:

INPUT:

```
val s1: String = "my.mail.google.com.xxx.hello.google.com"
val s2: String = "google.com"
```

OUTPUT:

```
val s3: String = "my.mail.google.com.xxx.hello"
```

Currently, I do:

```
s1.stripSuffix(s".$s2")
```

What is the most efficient solution to remove s2 from s1 so I get s3?
Is there faster solution than mine? Can I solve it with substring somehow? Would it be faster?

**EDIT**:
I am streaming 10^6 messages per second and I do apply such function on this data so yeah the performance does matter to me.

Comment: this feels like a micro-optimization...

Comment: @mck see my edit. ty

Comment: stripSuffix first validates that s2 exists in s1 and then calls substring if it does. If you know s2 exists, then you can write a custom stripSuffix which does not check beforehand. Secondly if s2 is constant, then you can pre calculate the length of the s2 for the substring method. Other than that if possible get a char array instead of String, reduce the size of the array and create the string.

Comment: yes, I know if s2 exists in s1 and I know the length of s2.

Comment: If, as you say, `s1` is known to have suffix `s2` and, therefore, the number of characters to be removed is known, then you should be able to `s3 = s1.dropRight(x)`, which is certainly simpler (and _should_ be faster) than `stripSuffix()`.